# HP Fortify BIRTReportGenerator Get New Issues Only

Tags: fortify

I'm trying to get a report with only the newest issues since last scan and at the command line. For example:

Scan 1: 5 issues

Scan 2: 8 issues

What I want: A report showing only the latest 3 issues

Here's my command so far:

```
.\BIRTReportGenerator.cmd -format "XLS" `
  -template "DISA STIG" `
  --Version "DISA STIG 4.3" `
  -source "C:\fortify\fortifyScan.fpr" `
  -output "C:\fortify\fortifyReport.xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you merge your new scan into the same FPR (either by scanning with `-f` set to an existing FPR with the older results, or by using `FPRUtility`), you can filter issues which are newly introduced to this scan by using a search string:

`[issue age]:new`

To use that with BIRTReportGenerator, add the switch `-searchQuery` and then your search, e.g.:

`BIRTReportGenerator -format XLS -template "DISA STIG" \
--Version "DISA STIG 4.3" -source your.fpr \
-output report.xls -searchQuery "[issue age]:new"`